# Generic completion passed as non-generic

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, protocols

I'm working on some framework and faced a problem.

I have a public protocol:

```
public protocol MyPublicProtocol1 {
}
```

And another one, which contains a function with generic argument passed. Generic argument has a constraint – argument type must implement the first public protocol:

```
public protocol MyPublicProtocol2 {
    func someFunc<T: MyPublicProtocol1>(completion: (T) -> ())
}
```

Then I'm implementing my protocols not in public classes. Inside that function with generic argument I have to call another one that takes not generic argument and look like that:

```
func anotherFuncWith(completion: (MyPublicProtocol1) -> ())
```

And here's what implementation looks like:

```
class MyPublicProtocol1Impl: MyPublicProtocol1 {
}

class MyPublicProtocol2Impl: MyPublicProtocol2 {
    func someFunc<T: MyPublicProtocol1>(completion: (T) -> ()) {
        anotherFuncWith(completion: completion)
    }
}
```

And of course I have an error in the last string.

I can't declare *someFunc(completion:)* with not a generic argument like:

```
func someFunc(completion: (MyPublicProtocol1Impl) -> ())
```

Because *MyPublicProtocol1Impl* class mustn't be public. And I also can't declare `anotherFuncWith(completion:)` to take generic argument too for some reasons.

Is there a way to somewhat "convert" `(T: MyPublicProtocol1) -> ()` completion to be just a `(MyPublicProtocol1) -> ()`?

Any help or advices are very appreciated! And thank you for reading my story!

Comment: I would recommend being more clear about the usage you're intending and the underlying problem you're trying to solve with your attempted solution.  often find the best solution is something different from my current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked for something that is not provably true. You have a method:

```
func anotherFuncWith(completion: (MyPublicProtocol1) -> ())
```

This accepts a method that can receive *any* `MyPublicProtocol1`. You then pass it a method of type:

```
(T: MyPublicProtocol1) -> ()
```

`anotherFuncWith` may pass something that is not `T`, at which point this is undefined. To make it more concrete, let's get rid of most of the stuff here and make `MyPublicProtocol1` be `Any` (just to pick a trivial protocol).

```
func anotherFuncWith(completion: (Any) -> ()) {
    completion("This is a string which is an Any, so that's fine")
}

func someFunc<T: Any>(completion: (T) -> ()) {
    anotherFuncWith(completion: completion)
}
```

This fails to compile exactly like your example. Now let's think through what I could do if it *did* compile. I could call:

```
func complete(x: Int) -> () {
    print(x + 1)
}

someFunc(completion: complete)
```

So now `anotherFuncWith` calls `complete` passing a `String`, which can't be added. Crash.

The underlying problem here is that you've gotten [covariance and contravariance](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html) backwards.

How do we fix it? Depends on what you really mean. This code is a little strange. Do you care about the actual type of `T` or not? You never seem to use it. If you don't care, then just use protocols:

```
public protocol MyPublicProtocol2 {
    func someFunc(completion: (MyPublicProtocol1) -> ())
}
```

If you do care about the actual type, use a PAT:

```
public protocol MyPublicProtocol2 {
    associatedtype T: MyPublicProtocol1
    func someFunc(completion: (T) -> ())
}
```

Or you may want to rethink whether you need a protocol here at all. I often find people reach for protocols when they don't need them yet. Do you have multiple implementations of these protocols? Do you have multiple types that are passed? If not, I'd simplify and only go generic/protocol when you have a real problem you're solving in the current code. (You may need them; this is just my stock advice that many people have found useful when they've over-designed.)

Answer (score 0):

The dirty way to get around this is

```
func someFunc<T: MyPublicProtocol1>(completion: (T) -> ()) {
    anotherFuncWith { (thing) in
        if let tThing = thing as? T {
            completion(tThing)
        }
    }
}
```

I would only do this if you are *very* sure of the code surrounding it as it is certainly fallible.

Also, this works too. I'm unsure what you're actually trying to do so I'm not sure if it solves your problem

```
func anotherFuncWith<T: MyPublicProtocol1>(completion: (T) -> ()) {

}

class MyPublicProtocol2Impl: MyPublicProtocol2 {

     func someFunc<T: MyPublicProtocol1>(completion: (T) -> ()) {
         anotherFuncWith(completion: completion)
    }
}
```